Golang serving static files with chi router error
package main

import (
    "log"
    "log/slog"
    "neo-foci-web/handlers"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)


func main(){

    if err:= godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    router := chi.NewMux();

    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/"))
    router.Handle("/public/*", http.StripPrefix("/public/", fileServer))
    // router.Handle("/*", publicf() );
    router.Get("/foo3", handlers.Make(handlers.HandleFoo));

    listenAddr := os.Getenv("LISTEN_ADDR");

    if listenAddr == "" {
        log.Fatal("LISTEN_ADDR is not set in env")
    }

    slog.Info("Https server started on port", "Listenaddr", listenAddr);

    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router);
}


thats my main.go. Eventhough i have multiple files in public forder i can not access them...
enter image description here
No matter what i do i will get 404 error... I have tried many approach...

Please minimise your example (e.g. this). Also please give an example of the URL you are attempting to access (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/test.html) and explain how you are running the code (if not from a command prompt then please try that; i.e. go build then ./neo-foci-web). ./ means your path is based on the working directory which may not be what you expect.

Somehow, after two days when i started the project it starts to work... I dont know how... but i will close this question.
